# Transform ellipsis in environment

Tags: r, list

I have a function and the arguments are lists. How to access the arguments and save its in environment? That is, each argument is an element of environment. For example:

```
a1 <- a2 <-  a3 <-  list()
a1 <- matrix(rnorm(6), ncol = 2)
a2 <- matrix(rnorm(6), ncol = 2)
a3 <- matrix(rnorm(6), ncol = 2)

#I know to access the `...` and save its in list, but I don't want to save in list.
f <- function(...){
  temp <- list(...)
  temp
}

tt <- f(a1, a2, a3) #return a list of list
#To access the argument one
tt[[1]]
```

But I want to save the arguments in a environment.

Comment: You question is not really clear. It would probably help to provide an example of your desired output.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Do you mean the return value should be a new `environment` object  (instead of a list) containing each of the arguments represented by `...`; or you want to pass in the environment where the arguments should be stored (e.g. the function signature would be something like `f <- function(env, ...) {}`)?

Comment: The first case.

Comment: Something like [this](https://gist.github.com/nathan-russell/af81dbaa2c426ff73ee55a1078e473f0#file-arg-env-r)?

Comment: I want that the new value of return is a new `environment` object (instead of list) containing each of the arguments represented by `...`.

Comment: Right, as my example demonstrated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns an environment using the argument as the name for any argument for which a name was not specified:

```
set.seed(123)
a1 <- matrix(rnorm(6), ncol = 2)
a2 <- matrix(rnorm(6), ncol = 2)
a3 <- matrix(rnorm(6), ncol = 2)

f2 <- function(...) {
  L <- list(...)
  nms <- names(L)
  if (is.null(nms)) nms <- character(length(L))  # vector of "" elements
  names(L) <- ifelse(nms == "", as.character(match.call()[-1]), nms)
  list2env(L)
}

e <- f2(a1, a2, a3)
ls(e)
## [1] "a1" "a2" "a3"

e <- f2(2 * a1, X = a2, a3)
ls(e)
## [1] "2 * a1" "a3"     "X"
```

The above is really a bit messy and one would not expect that variables are automatically named.  It would be simpler to just require that the caller specify the names:

```
f3 <- function(...) list2env(list(...))
e <- f3(a1 = a1, a2 = a2, a3 = a3)
ls(e)
## [1] "a1" "a2" "a3"
```

**Note:** The first line of code in the question, i.e. `a1 <- a2 <- a3 <- list()`, has no effect since the 3 variables are overwritten in the next 3 lines.